# What exactly is the motive of Frank Sr/Jr behind the 'lost and found necklace' act?

Tags: plot-explanation, catch-me-if-you-can

In the movie *Catch Me If You Can*, both Frank Sr and Frank Jr try to trick the female employees by falsely pointing out that they found a necklace and ask them (the female employees) if it is theirs.

By doing so maybe he'd get a little more attention from the lady but is he really hoping that merely by showing her the necklace, he'd get his work done, or does he actually end up giving that necklace in which case it becomes a bribe?

What exactly is Frank's play here?

Comment: Bribery, flattery, distraction,... The necklace is likely worthless.

Comment: I think that you are under wrong impression that a) those women don't take the presented necklace and b) that it is valuable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What exactly is Frank's play here?

### He is overstating the value of the gift to his "marks" to make them do as he wants.

Both Frank and his father say "I think it has slipped off your neck" showing the targeted woman a golden necklace. It doesn't mean that they expect their target to say "sorry, it's not mine" (and then Frank would then hide it back to his pocket) - no, the target is expected to take it, especially since Frank and his dad are charming enough to make their "marks" to accept this bribery. Once the women have taken this gift, they are more inclined to give something in return -  the value of the gift is meaningless and in this case probably quite low.